# Golang Slice Indexing Value Or Reference?

Tags: go, slice

I am learning go and is confused by the "thing" we get out of indexing a slice.
Consider that we have a struct of type `bag`:

```golang
type bag struct {
    item string
}
```

Then, consider that we have a list of bags:

```golang
itemBag := []bag{
    {item: "item1"},
    {item: "item2"},
    {item: "item3"}
}
```

Now, I try to change the content of the first element of our `itemBag` variable. Naively, I do the following:

```golang
item1 := itemBag[0]
item1.item = "not item1"

fmt.Printf("itemBag[0].item == 'not item1'? %v", itemBag[0].item == "not item1")

// console print false
```

I got the answer as false, because (I think, do correct me if I am wrong) when we do `item1 := itemBag[0]`, we are making a copy of the value of `itemBag[0]` and assign it to `item1`. Which I believe is what is meant by [this blog here](https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro).

To prove that, I try to obtain the pointer of the `itemBag[0]` instead and modify its value, and voila, I achieve what I wanted to do:

```golang
item1 := &itemBag[0]
item1.item = "not item1"

fmt.Printf("itemBag[0].item == 'not item1'? %v", itemBag[0].item == "not item1")

// console print true
```

Which makes a lot of sense if we say that when we do slice indexing (i.e. slice[index]) we'll get copy of its value instead of the underlying item.

Now, when I do the following instead:

```golang
itemBag[0].item = "not item1"

fmt.Printf("itemBag[0].item == 'not item1'? %v", itemBag[0].item == "not item1")
```

The result is `true`, which is not what I expected. **Because it looks like `itemBag[0].item` is syntatically the same as if I first assign `itemBag[0]` to a variable and subsequently referring to its underlying item.**

I feel like I am missing a basic chapter in the golang course, please, any redirection/explanation will be highly appreciated!

Tried googling things like "slice indexing pass by reference" but couldn't pinpoint the exact keywords to google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assignment operation copies values. So when you do:

```
item1 = itemBag[0]
```

you create a copy of the object at `itemBag[0]`, which is of type `bag`. Now `item1` has a copy of it, and any modifications you make to it will be made on the copy.

```
itemptr = &itemBag[0]
```

The right-side of the assignment is a pointer, so this operation creates a copy of that pointer and assigns it to `itemptr`. When you do `itemptr.item="x"`, it is equivalent to `(*itemptr).item=x`, so the contents of the pointer is modified.

`itemBag[0]` is an addressable value, i.e. you can take the address of it.

https://go.dev/ref/spec#Address_operators

The expression `itemBag[0].item` is also an addressable value, so you can assign something to it, and it will be reflected in the slice itself.

The following, however, is not an addressable value:

```
m:=map[int]bag{1:bag{item:"str"}}
m[1].item="str1"
```

This is because `m[1]` returns a copy of a value in a map, and assigning a value to it would be lost. The following, however, is addressable:

```
m:=map[int]*bag{1:&bag{item:"str"}}
m[1].item="str1"
```

This would set the `item` field of the `bag` in the map.

Comment: Ah, ok so my confusion is really the result of missing 2 important concepts: a) assignment operation copies values. (the pointer assignment is in fact copying the value, but instead of the value, I am copying the pointer which explain why I can modify the underlying value) b) the 'addressability' concept in golang - which I'll need to study more. It's so much more clearer now, thanks a lot!